# Is there any problem with my code? I think there's all good

Tags: javascript

I've been using the jQ recently and it looks like I've forgotten js

*my code*

```
 var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (var i =0; i > li.length; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.style.color = 'red';
    });
```

Comment: i < li.length , it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the loop be like below :

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (var i =0; i <li.length; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.style.color = 'red';
    });
}
```

Comment: Yup... you're right. var i should be less than li.length but the main problem is that the console shows Uncaught Syntexerror: Unexpected end of output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have `i < li.length` there and you will be good.

Comment: Thank you for you interest but the problem is that the console shows "Uncaught Syntexerror: Unexpected end of output". 
I thought maybe i'd indenting problem and did try by indenting the codes properly but it didn't solve the problem.